# Imperatively remount server component in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to imperatively remount a server component from a client component with Next 13's App Router?

Say I have the following page. `<ClientFormComponent />` sends a fetch request to an API end point to add data, and `ServerList` pulls data from that end point:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <ClientFormComponent />

      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <ServerList />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

How can I tell `<ServerList />` that the data has changed?

I've tried:

- Adding a key to `<ServerList />` to tell it to re-render - I think this would require `<ServerList />` to be a client component
- Using `revalidateTag` and `revalidatePath` to mark the data as stale in an API route - the server component did not update.

Is the only option to mark everything as client side and fall back to `useEffect` for data fetching?

Comment: Have you tried `router.refresh()` after `revalidateTag`/`revalidatePath`?

Comment: I have, and it seems to give me a full-page reload, which isn't quite what I'm after.

Comment: Are you sure? This is what the documentation says. router.refresh(): Refresh the current route. Making a new request to the server, re-fetching data requests, and re-rendering Server Components. The client will merge the updated React Server Component payload without losing unaffected client-side React (e.g. useState) or browser state (e.g. scroll position).

Comment: So it _does_ seem to keep client side state, but if I look at my devtools, it's doing a full GET request to the page's URL, and I'm losing scroll position.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work properly when I run `next build` then `next start` vs `next dev`. I guess that's it, thanks for your help!